# Help with trigonometric equation $\tan(x)+\cot(2x)=1$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve the equation $\tan(x)+\cot(2x)=1$.

It is clear that the equation has a solution $x=\pi/4$ but I can't show that this is the only solution. Any ideas?

P.S. I am trying to solve the equation without using formulas for $2a$ angle

Comment: For what $x$? Is $x$ restricted to $[0,\pi]$?

Comment: Why are you avoiding the double angle formulas? It's pretty hard to avoid them.

Comment: No Frpzzd it's not restricted.

Comment: The exercise was given to me this way. I know how to solve it with double angle formulas. I don't know if it is possible to solve it without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\tan x=t$

$$1=t+\dfrac{1-t^2}{2t}$$

$$\iff2t=1+t^2\iff(t-1)^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have to use double angle formulas at all...

$$\tan (x) + \cot 2x = 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac {\sin x}{\cos x} + \dfrac {\cos 2x}{\sin 2x} 
 =1 \Rightarrow \dfrac {\sin x \sin 2x + \cos x \cos 2x}{\cos x \sin 2x} = 1$$

A couple of hints:

1. What trick can you use to simplify ${\sin x \sin 2x + \cos x \cos 2x}$?
2. Are there any extraneous roots?  ($\frac {\pi}{4}$ is correct; the general solution would be $\frac {\pi}{4} \pm \pi k$.)

Comment: I know this solution. It 's $\sin x\sin2x+\cos x\cos 2x=\cos(2x-x)=\cos x$, thus we have $\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos x\sin x}=1\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{\sin 2x}=1\Rightarrow \sin2x=1$. But I think it's kind the same with double angle. Anyway thanks for answering